# Reversing ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist, reverse

All im trying to do is reverse the ArrayList. Is there a way I could do it through the toString as well or should I just create a method like I did. Im so close, any answers will help! Thanks!

```
  package edu.purse.test;

  java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Collections;

   public class Purse 
 {
ArrayList<String> coins = new ArrayList<String>();
public Purse()
{

}
public void addCoin(String coinName)
{

    coins.add(coinName);
}
public String toString()
{
    return  "Purse" + coins.toString();
}
public ArrayList<String> getReversed(ArrayList<String> coins) 
{ 
ArrayList<String> copy = new ArrayList<String>(coins); 
Collections.reverse(copy); 
return copy; 
}

 }
```

TESTERCLASS

```
    package edu.purse.test;

  import java.util.Collections;
   import java.util.List;

  public class PurseTester {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Purse p = new Purse();
    p.addCoin("Quarter");
    p.addCoin("Dime");
    p.addCoin("Nickel");
    p.addCoin("Penny");
    System.out.println(p.toString());

    p.getReversed(coins);
}
```

}

Answer (score 7):

The method

```
p.getReversed(coins);
```

returns a reversed list. You can just print it out

```
System.out.println(p.getReversed(coins));
```

Note that you are getting a copy of your instance's list, reversing that, and then returning it. If you want to preserve the change, simple call `Collections.reverse()` on the original, `coins`.

Comment: Ok once I do System.out.println(getReversed(coins)) in the tester class it says that coins cannot be resolved as a variable. It is because I named my ArrayList<String> in the class and not the tester class?

Comment: @ChanceSmith Variables have a scope (keyword, look it up for more details). They can only be used in the scope they are declared in. The variable `coins` is an instance member of the `Purse` so you can only access it through a reference to a `Purse` object or inside an instance method of `Purse`.

Comment: I understand that so how would I be able to pull that ArrayList<String> coin into the tester class. Make a new ArrayList<String>?

Comment: @ChanceSmith Take a look [at this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html). It's good practice to declare your member variables as `private` and use getters to retrieve them. You should be able to use a getter for your `coins` variable.

Comment: The assignment makes me make a method for adding the coins.  I can't use getters and setters.

Comment: @chance Then you shouldn't be accessing `coins` externally, ie. from your tester class.

Comment: Your right I didn't even need the parameter in the getReversed method. Thanks!

Comment: @chance You're welcome. Consider accepting answers to your questions. They will be more inclined to help you in the future and it helps others see what worked more easily.

Comment: I tried doing that but it says users with reputation of less than 10 cant reply for 8 hours. I guess its telling me that I should help other people as well lol

Comment: @chance Ah, no (well yes help others if you can). It's probably a measure against farming rep.